# Set default form fields based on fetched data from entity

Tags: php, symfony

Ok my update is working just fine but i used fetched data and passed to formclass constructor and in from class i used 'data' so i can have default value set in form when i wanted to do update. It is working but it is not how it is supposed to be done... Here is my code..

CONTROLLER:

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/{slug}/update", name="update_post")
 */
public function updatePostAction(Request $request, $slug) {
    if(!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $postUpdate = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')
        ->findOneByName($slug);

    $name = $post_update->getName();
    $content = $post_update->getContent();
    $visible = $post_update->getVisible();

    $form = $this->createForm(new PostForm($name, $content, $visible), $postUpdate, array(
        'action' => 'update',
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

    }
    return $this->render (
      'create/post.html.twig', array(
         'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

Form Class:

```
class PostForm extends AbstractType {
private $name;
private $content;
private $visible;
private $button = "Create Post";
public function __construct($name="", $content="", $visible=array(1,0)) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->visible = $visible;
    if ($this->name!="") {
        $this->button = "Update Post";
    }
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'data' => $this->name
        ))
        ->add('content', 'textarea', array(
            'data' => $this->content
        ))
        ->add('visible', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                1 => 1,
                0 => 0
            )
        ))
        ->add('publishDate', 'date', array(
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'choice'
        ))
        ->add('belongToPage', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Page',
            'property' => 'name',
            'choice_label' => 'getName', //getName is function from class Page which returns name of page(s)
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => $this->button));
}

public function getName()
{
    // TODO: Implement getName() method.
}
}
```

Comment: what is the question? you want to use another method?

Comment: i am passing values for form fields (this is for update not create so fields for update cant be empty) throught createForm and form class constructor.. It shouldnt be done like that, it should be able to pull these datas without me doing it like this...

Comment: Still not understanding.  For example, there should be no need to use the data attribute for the name element.  Are you saying that without it the name value does not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony will bind values from **AppBundle:Post** Entity automatically when this Post entity is passed to form builder (as a second argument of createForm). Please notice that form field must have exactly the same name as Post Entity property.
New values (from POST/GET request) symfony2 will bind to Post Entity during call of **handleRequest** method.

**Notice**: please do not pass arguments to formType by constructor - this is a bad practice (in symfony2). please use third builder argument (options)

**QUESTION**: $post_update should be $postUpdate, right?

Comment: Yes $post_update is $postUpdate, i switched to camelcase looks like i forgot to change all..

I solved it by passing $postUpdate to form class constructor and deleted all array('data' => $something) in form class because i dont need it anymore.. 

$form = $this->createForm(new PostForm($postUpdate), $postUpdate)

this is much better than way i used in example above when i manually entered all default form field values...